# Python mysterious error

Tags: python

So I am working on a program to create portmanteaus. I have the code and functions I need, and I have put them together.

Here is the code:

```
def portmanteauscore(start, mid, end):
    totallen = len(start) + len(mid) + len(end)
    return totallen - abs((len(start)/totallen) - len(start)) - abs((len(mid)/totallen) - len(mid)) - abs((len(end)/totallen) - len(end))


def portmanteaugenerator(word1, word2, words):
    mid = longest_common_substring(word1, word2)
    start = word1[:word1.index(mid)]
    end = word2[len(mid):]
    if start + mid in words and mid + end in words:
        return start, mid, end


def natalie(words):
    "Find the best Portmanteau word formed from any two of the list of words."
    wordpermutations = list(itertools.permutations(words))
    maxscore, bestnatalie = 0, ''
    for perm in wordpermutations:
        start, mid, end = portmanteaugenerator(perm[0], perm[1], words)
        if portmanteauscore(start, mid, end) > maxscore:
            bestnatalie, maxscore = start + mid + end, portmanteauscore(start, mid, end)
    print bestnatalie
    return bestnatalie


def longest_common_substring(s1, s2):
    m = [[0] * (1 + len(s2)) for i in xrange(1 + len(s1))]
    longest, x_longest = 0, 0
    for x in xrange(1, 1 + len(s1)):
        for y in xrange(1, 1 + len(s2)):
            if s1[x - 1] == s2[y - 1]:
                m[x][y] = m[x - 1][y - 1] + 1
                if m[x][y] > longest:
                    longest = m[x][y]
                    x_longest = x
            else:
                m[x][y] = 0
    return s1[x_longest - longest: x_longest]
```

But when I run the code, I keep getting this error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
  import main
   File "/tmp/vmuser_ijxrjleuxj/main.py", line 107, in <module>
   print test_natalie()
  File "/tmp/vmuser_ijxrjleuxj/main.py", line 87, in test_natalie
assert natalie(['adolescent', 'scented', 'centennial', 'always', 'ado']) in        ('adolescented','adolescentennial')
  File "/tmp/vmuser_ijxrjleuxj/main.py", line 67, in natalie
     start,mid,end=portmanteaugenerator(perm[0],perm[1],words)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This occurs when I return the start,mid,and end variables for the portmanteau generator. When given a list of words, it should return a portmanteau from two words that is the best according to portmanteau score.

But I keep getting this type error for some reason. I have tried making start,mid,end a list and it still fails to run. Can you please help me?

Comment: More spaces! Spaces after commas and around binary operators would make this a lot more readable.

Comment: Ironic when talking about a portmanteaugenerator ;)

Answer (score 6):

Most likely, `start+mid in words and mid+end in words` returns `False` and so the function, instead of passing through the `if-statement`, returns `None` (because if a function does not return something, it defaults to `None`).

Then you're trying to do something like:

```
start,mid,end = None
```

What python is trying to do is split up `None` in those three variables. It's like doing this:

```
one, two, three = (1, 2, 3)
```

But you can't, because `None` is not an iterable.